# turn off pitch correction in VLC when speed is changed

Tags: vlc

Is it possible to turn off pitch correction in VLC?  I cannot find instructions on this anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For VLC for Android, v. 1.7.5, the required setting is in the "Extra Settings" section under the "Performance" menu and is called "Time-Stretching Audio".

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to turn it off in preferences, check https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=66188 . Hope this helps.

Comment: I think that's for the desktop version of vlc